# Something prevents me from reaching no space left on iPod

Tags: ios, itunes, hard-drive

I want to reach the disk space limit of my iPod touch to handle the 'no space left' condition in my app. In order to do that, I've been sending big files to fill the space of the disk.

I send the files with iTunes, but somehow the memory limit is never reached. It seems that everytime I try to reach the limit with these transfers, iTunes is automatically copying older files from my ipod to my macbook in order to create space for the new files. At least it seems so, but I'm not sure. Something else could be happening but I don't know what.

My iPod touch is on iOS 9.3.5 and I have the latest macbook pro.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please see [ask] for tips on asking questions.  Please [edit] your question to include the iOS/macOS versions, what hardware you have, and how you're connecting to iTunes.

Comment: I've never heard of testing storage pressure - the system literally shuts down. What would your app do anything for a low storage situation other than write files to the proper locations so that the system cleans cache and downloaded content automatically? I'm wondering if you mean memory pressure and not storage pressure - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/responding_to_memory_warnings

Comment: My app is a video encoder, and I would like to show a popup when there is no space left on the disk

Comment: 1. Why is that a problem? 2. Why can’t you do your own calculations for if/when disk is empty?

Comment: 1. It's a problem because I don't want the app to crash for that, I can just display a pop up. 2 It's hard to estimate the size of an encoded video so that would not work in every case, and also because I'm curious about what happens when the limit is reached during the encoding process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after hours, the only solution I found to get an error (AVErrorDiskFull) was to disable iCloud and internet, and keep creating videos in the phone. Even if sometimes it said 0 bytes left, I could still add other videos, but at some point, I finally got the error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this was available on iOS 9.5 but on iOS 11 there is an option to conserve space on ios devices. What this does is remove apps that you haven't used to make rooom for new apps or files. I suppose it only removes Apple Store apps since you can easily restore those. this sure sounds like what your iPod may be doing. On my iphone this is turned on by going to Settings/General/iPhone Storge. There is an option there to turn it on. To turn it off go to 'iTunes and App Store' and scroll down to Offload Unused Apps and turn it off there.